# How to capture click events on different views in a list item?

Tags: android, listview, listener, adapter

I have a list view with an image view and text in a linear layout. I want to perform different operations when user clicks on the Image view and the Text view. I have tried onItemClickListener but it's capturing on the whole linear layout. I tried onClickListener in custom adapter, but were unable to get its position.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i m sharing my code.i have three Textviews in each list item and on one of them i put a listener.This code is for reference.Learning from the below code U can put listeners on different list items.Now i hope u can write code as u want.

```
static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;

        }

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = null;
    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.attach_pic, null);

        holder.tv1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.defectpic);
        holder.tv2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.no_of_uploded_pics);
        holder.tv3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.camera);

        holder.tv3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(TAG, position);
                context.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

            }
        });

        rowView.setTag(holder);
        List itemVal1 = (List)getItem(position);
        String st1 = (String)itemVal1.get(0);
        holder.tv1.setText(st1);

        List itemVal2 = (List)getItem(position);
        String st2 = (String)itemVal2.get(1);
        holder.tv2.setText(st2);

    } else {
        rowView = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) rowView.getTag()).tv1.setTag(list.get(position));
        ((ViewHolder) rowView.getTag()).tv2.setTag(list.get(position));
        ((ViewHolder) rowView.getTag()).tv3.setTag(list.get(position));
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set tag for each view you are going to click as its position & get that using gettag

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make both your textview and the imageview clickable and focusable.

Secondly Inside Your adapter class within getView add events to both textview and imageview.